# Bit masking and separation in c

Tags: c, numbers, separator, bitmask

I am new to c programming and i need help in bit manipulation.
I would  like to separate the number from a register which have  encoded numbers in BCD.
for example;

the register got '29' as value    two bits will denote 2 ='10' and four bits will denote 9='1001'.
It is an 8 bit register and rest bits are zero.
So  shifting out the 4 bits will give me 2 at disposal.But what about getting the unit digit?
I need some help regarding that
I'm posting the code here:

```
  #include<stdio.h>
    main()
 {
     int x,y;
     y=0x29;
      x=y;
     x=x>>4;
    x=x*10;
    printf("%d",x);
    return(0);

 }
```

Comment: Use whitespace, proper indentation, and declare an `int` return value for `main()`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to mask it out with binary `00001111`, which is decimal 15 or hexadecimal `0x0f`.

```
uint8_t reg = 41; // binary 00101001
uint8_t lo_nibble = (reg >> 0) & 0x0f;
uint8_t hi_nibble = (reg >> 4) & 0x0f;
```

Comment: Thank you very much.It works.Can you explain the theory behind this.

Comment: @ArunNr I could, but I'm not willing to (on purpose). Do some research, read up on bit operations and the `>>` and `&` operators, and/or find one of the various duplicates here on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Thank you very much.I tried out in paper and now it is in my head.

Comment: @ArunNr You see? :) I'm glad you now understand it. You're welcome.

Comment: If this answer was useful to you, please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/227203). See _[How does accepting an answer work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/227203)_ to learn more.

Answer (score 0):

To form a mask to capture the bottom *n* bits of a number, you can perform these steps (pen and paper at first, eventually in your head):

- start with the value 1.
  `(1)` // == 1 or 00000001
- shift the value 1 *up* by *n* bits.
  `(1<<4)` // == 16 or 00010000
- subtract 1.
  `(1<<4)-1` // == 15 or 00001111

ANDing this mask with another value or variable will yield the bottom *n* bits of the number.

```
int in, hi, lo;

lo = in & ((1<<4)-1);
hi = (in>>4) & ((1<<4)-1);
```